# Monterey Time Machine backups to Synology result in umount 100% cpu

Tags: time-machine, nas, monterey

I'm using a Synology NAS as a target for Time Machine backup on macOS Monterey.
Quite frequently, this results in an unkillable `umount` spinning a core at 100%.

This started after I upgraded my trashcan-shaped Mac Pro from Mojave or Catalina (I forget which!) to Monterey.

Truly weird is that this hangs any Chrome windows trying to load web pages.
Nothing I've found other than waiting a few minutes until it finishes.

Anyone else experienced this? How would I go about digging? Anyone know of a fix?

[This](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252056670) sounds similar but opposite: Safari's fine for me, but Chrome locks up. No answers on that thread either.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact same issue (Synology TM backups, umount process at 100%, upgrade from Catalina to Monterey).

Until I can find a root cause, I was able to force quit via the command line, assuming there is a single `umount` process running:

1. Open a Terminal window
2. `sudo kill -KILL $(pgrep umount)` (this will prompt for your OS X password).

Comment: In my case, the `umount` in unkillable. What version of DSM are you on? I'm on 6.2.4-25556 Update 5, which affected SMB and NFS, so fingers crossed...

Comment: Exact same boat here. umount and diskarbitrationd are unkillable.  Chrome tabs lock up and stop loading.  Safari seems to work, but I don't use it extensively enough to know whether it would lock up too under similar use.  Didn't start happening until I upgraded to Monterey (12.4).